# Need help on Objective-C code generated from wsdl2objc webservice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, wsdl

I am new to iPhone development. I am trying out to generate a proxy server at a client side using a wsdl2objc web service. I went through [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) and am doing a sample application using this tutorial.

Actually I have two strings s1 and s2 I need to concatenate the two strings and display the result on a textfield using a button. I have generated code out of the wsdl2objc file. The name of the generated class is `SimpleService`.

As I am new to iphone development, the generated code contains many methods where I am confused which class to be used. I have a written code which compiles correctly but still its not executing. Where I am going wrong? What corrections need to be done in the following code?

```
@implementation WsdlViewController
@synthesize field;
-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender
{
    SimpleServiceSOAP *binding = [SimpleService SimpleServiceSOAP];
    binding.logXMLInOut = YES;
    SimpleService_concat *testParams = [[SimpleService_concat new]autorelease];
    testParams.s1 = field.text;   // parameters all become properties of this testParams object
    testParams.s2 = field.text;          
    SimpleServiceSOAPResponse * response = [binding   concatUsingParameters: testParams];  
                                   [response self];
    NSArray * responseBodyParts = response.bodyParts;
    NSError *responseError = response.error;
    for (id bodypart in responseBodyParts)
    {
        if ([bodypart  isKindOfClass:[SimpleService_concat class]])
        {
           SimpleService_concat * body = (SimpleService_concat *)bodypart; 
            field.text = body.s1;
            field.text = body.s2;
        }
    }    
}
```

u wan me to provide wsdl2objc generated code?

Comment: what does actually happen ? your app crashes ?

Comment: @vince ya when i press button it crashes and shows many thread...

Comment: Does the log show good XML getting sent and received? I agree it's tough to troubleshoot; put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method, and step through it until you see where it breaks. I've written several wsdl2objc tutorials myself; the latest one is at http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2011/05/iphone-development-accessing-soap.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about wsdl2objc at all.
However, after reading the code, it seems to me the heart is based on these two lines :

```
field.text = body.s1;
field.text = body.s2;
```

As your explanation is you want to concatenate two strings and display the result in the field, you should try replacing the two lines above, with :

```
field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", body.s1, body.s2];
```

This concatenates the two strings and assign the result to the `text` property of `field`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank u for ur response..ya when i click the button it is throwing exceptions like Thread...i dont know where i am going wrong as i am new to iphone development...even i changed the code as u suggested still it doesnt work...wsdl2objc generated code has many files in which many methods r written we need to access those methods in the above code...so bit confusing to access which to which one...still i have tried writing above code following the tutorial..where can i share full code?